# error installing depth_nav_tools

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-kinetic, buiding-errors, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am trying to install  `depth_nav_tools`, however, the catkin_make fails with errors:

```
In file included from /home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp:37:0:
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/include/nav_layer_from_points/costmap_layer.h:95:3: error: ‘tf’ does not name a type
   tf::TransformListener tf_;
   ^
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void nav_layer_from_points::NavLayerFromPoints::updateBounds(double, double, double, double*, double*, double*, double*)’:
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp:127:13: error: request for member ‘transformPoint’ in ‘((nav_layer_from_points::NavLayerFromPoints*)this)->nav_layer_from_points::NavLayerFromPoints::<anonymous>.costmap_2d::Layer::tf_’, which is of pointer type ‘tf2_ros::Buffer*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
         tf_.transformPoint(global_frame, pt, out_pt);
             ^
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp:136:13: error: ‘tf’ does not name a type
       catch(tf::LookupException& ex)
             ^
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp:136:32: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
       catch(tf::LookupException& ex)
                                ^
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp:136:32: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp:136:32: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘&’ token
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp:136:34: error: ‘ex’ was not declared in this scope
       catch(tf::LookupException& ex)
                                  ^
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp:141:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘catch’
       catch(tf::ConnectivityException& ex)
       ^
/home/mars-lab/catkin_ws/src/depth_nav_tools/nav_layer_from_points/src/costmap_layer.cpp:146:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘catch’
       catch(tf::ExtrapolationException& ex)
       ^
```

I am not sure how to fix this, can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Regards,
hdbot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318763/error-installing-depth_nav_tools/) by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2019-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This would seem to be a case of `nav_layer_from_points` not declaring a (build) dependency on `tf`.

See the [build script](https://github.com/mdrwiega/depth_nav_tools/blob/43914262d1e517136351b8b2b367067df5c6b677/nav_layer_from_points/CMakeLists.txt): the `tf` package is not mentioned anywhere. Neither in the [package manifest](https://github.com/mdrwiega/depth_nav_tools/blob/43914262d1e517136351b8b2b367067df5c6b677/nav_layer_from_points/package.xml).

It's likely that the `tf` dependency was brought in transitively by some other dependency of `nav_layer_from_points`.

It will probably start working if you add `tf` to the `find_package(catkin REQUIRED ..)` and the `catkin_package(.. CATKIN_DEPENDS ..)` calls in the build script and as a `depend` to the package manifest.

If you do, and that fixes things, a PR to the original repository contributing that fix would probably be appreciated by the author.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on 2019-03-19**:
@gvdhoorn I tried this, and it didn't work. Still getting same error when building the package.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-19**:
Have you made sure to first delete your `build` and `devel` directories before trying to run `catkin_make` again?

**Comment by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on 2019-03-19**:
@gvdhoorn, Yes I had tried deleting old build and devel. I got the package installed. It needed `#include <tf/transform_listener.h>` in the `costmap_layer.h` file. Once you include that, it works fine with your suggestion.